# MySQL shutting down on ~ same time and is not starting. Brute Force Attack? Or what?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, brute-force-attacks

my portal started to shutting down (1 time a day) and it happening over a week now and i do not know were could issue be. ..

MySQL is shutting down on about the same time and is not starting after that.
I see on mysql error logs multiple connection denied to multiple users from multiple IP's:

```
2020-02-03T17:37:30.226268Z 5556 [Warning] IP address '118.193.28.58' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2020-02-03T17:37:30.489071Z 5556 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'118.193.28.58' (using password: NO)
2020-02-03T17:37:31.255169Z 5557 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'118.193.28.58' (using password: YES)
2020-02-03T17:37:32.011111Z 5558 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'118.193.28.58' (using password: YES)
2020-02-03T17:37:32.766829Z 5559 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'118.193.28.58' (using password: YES)
2020-02-03T17:37:33.523834Z 5560 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'118.193.28.58' (using password: YES)
2020-02-03T17:37:34.308241Z 5561 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'118.193.28.58' (using password: YES)
2020-02-03T17:37:35.130693Z 5562 [Note] Access denied for user 'mysql'@'118.193.28.58' (using password: YES)
2020-02-03T17:37:35.959631Z 5563 [Note] Access denied for user 'mysqld'@'118.193.28.58' (using password: YES)
2020-02-03T17:37:36.819837Z 5564 [Note] Access denied for user 'mysqld'@'118.193.28.58' (using password: YES)
```

First i get multiple access denied:

```
2020-02-05T04:27:31.476393Z 8281 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'88.214.26.19' (using password: YES)
2020-02-05T04:32:07.783157Z 8294 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'88.214.26.20' (using password: YES)
2020-02-05T04:36:43.324917Z 8305 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'88.214.26.39' (using password: YES)
2020-02-05T04:41:18.711229Z 8314 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'88.214.26.40' (using password: YES)
2020-02-05T04:45:51.599383Z 8325 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'88.214.26.17' (using password: YES)
2020-02-05T04:50:27.407846Z 8334 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'88.214.26.18' (using password: YES)
```

And it looks like MySQL is shutting down after that:

```
2020-02-05T04:51:09.548048Z 0 [Note] Giving 2 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2020-02-05T04:51:09.548078Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2020-02-05T04:51:11.548170Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 2 remaining clients
2020-02-05T04:51:11.548216Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 8003  user: ''

2020-02-05T04:51:11.548252Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 8345  user: ''

2020-02-05T04:51:11.548274Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2020-02-05T04:51:11.548355Z 8345 [Note] Bad handshake
2020-02-05T04:51:11.548393Z 8003 [Note] Bad handshake
2020-02-05T04:51:11.548685Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552386Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'validate_password'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552407Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'auth_socket'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552410Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552413Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552417Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552420Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552423Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552501Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552509Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552514Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552518Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552538Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552540Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552543Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552565Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552568Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552571Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552574Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552577Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552673Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552678Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552733Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552736Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552739Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552743Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552746Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552749Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552752Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552755Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552758Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552761Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552764Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552768Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552771Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552774Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552777Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552792Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552795Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552917Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552924Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2020-02-05T04:51:11.552994Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-02-05T04:51:11.553205Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-02-05T04:51:11.653467Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-02-05T04:51:11.654368Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200205  6:51:11
2020-02-05T04:51:12.889032Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 5451240039
2020-02-05T04:51:12.898916Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-02-05T04:51:12.898935Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2020-02-05T04:51:12.898942Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-02-05T04:51:12.898946Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2020-02-05T04:51:12.898950Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2020-02-05T04:51:12.899190Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2020-02-05T04:51:12.900006Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2020-02-05T04:51:13.397754Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-02-05T04:51:13.399389Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 60962 ...
2020-02-05T04:51:13.404126Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-02-05T04:51:13.404150Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-02-05T04:51:13.404154Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-02-05T04:51:13.404159Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-02-05T04:51:13.404163Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-02-05T04:51:13.404167Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-02-05T04:51:13.405064Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-02-05T04:51:13.405218Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-02-05T04:51:13.408138Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-02-05T04:51:13.418099Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-02-05T04:51:13.420971Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-02-05T04:51:13.432975Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-02-05T04:51:13.609510Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-02-05T04:51:13.609610Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-02-05T04:51:14.458761Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-02-05T04:51:14.460267Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-02-05T04:51:14.460278Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-02-05T04:51:14.461182Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-02-05T04:51:14.511398Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.29 started; log sequence number 5451240039
2020-02-05T04:51:14.512389Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-02-05T04:51:14.512403Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-02-05T04:51:14.519095Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-02-05T04:51:14.519109Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-02-05T04:51:14.519970Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-02-05T04:51:14.520010Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-02-05T04:51:14.534481Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-02-05T04:51:14.539722Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200205  6:51:14
2020-02-05T04:51:14.544074Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.GFPeHcflSb/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu)
2020-02-05T04:51:14.560728Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2020-02-05T04:51:14.560745Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2020-02-05T04:51:14.560752Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2020-02-05T04:51:14.560838Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561157Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561166Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561169Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561173Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561176Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561193Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561196Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561201Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561204Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561207Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561209Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561212Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561215Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561217Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561220Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561223Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561225Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561228Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561231Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561233Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561236Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561238Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561241Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561244Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561247Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561249Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561252Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561254Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561257Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561260Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561262Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561265Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561268Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561270Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561273Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561276Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561278Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561281Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561310Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-02-05T04:51:14.561407Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-02-05T04:51:14.661755Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-02-05T04:51:14.662100Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200205  6:51:14
2020-02-05T04:51:16.178302Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 5451240058
2020-02-05T04:51:16.179749Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-02-05T04:51:16.179762Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2020-02-05T04:51:16.179775Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-02-05T04:51:16.179780Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2020-02-05T04:51:16.179783Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2020-02-05T04:51:16.179947Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2020-02-05T04:51:16.180256Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

2020-02-05T05:36:08.117851Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-02-05T05:36:08.120175Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 65398 ...
2020-02-05T05:36:08.125444Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-02-05T05:36:08.125485Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-02-05T05:36:08.125490Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-02-05T05:36:08.125514Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-02-05T05:36:08.125518Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-02-05T05:36:08.125522Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-02-05T05:36:08.125929Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-02-05T05:36:08.126199Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-02-05T05:36:08.130411Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-02-05T05:36:08.140643Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-02-05T05:36:08.144417Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-02-05T05:36:08.156510Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-02-05T05:36:08.324289Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-02-05T05:36:08.324369Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-02-05T05:36:09.166154Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-02-05T05:36:09.166978Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-02-05T05:36:09.166988Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-02-05T05:36:09.168381Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.29 started; log sequence number 5451240058
2020-02-05T05:36:09.169574Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-02-05T05:36:09.169915Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-02-05T05:36:09.178288Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-02-05T05:36:09.178363Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-02-05T05:36:09.178805Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200205  7:36:09
2020-02-05T05:36:09.178943Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-02-05T05:36:09.178973Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-02-05T05:36:09.179105Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2020-02-05T05:36:09.179262Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-02-05T05:36:09.179272Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-02-05T05:36:09.179301Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-02-05T05:36:09.189417Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-02-05T05:36:09.189677Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2020-02-05T05:36:21.428034Z 2 [Warning] IP address 'MYREALIP' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
```

The question is is this a Brute Force Attack? If yes how can i fight it?
If no whats wrong then?

P.S. `auth.log` also shows interesting things. .. Here are part of it

```
...
Feb  4 09:38:11 sshd[75190]: Failed password for invalid user octsr from 188.166.232.29 port 41336 ssh2
Feb  4 09:38:12  sshd[75190]: Received disconnect from 188.166.232.29 port 41336:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb  4 09:38:12 sshd[75190]: Disconnected from invalid user octsr 188.166.232.29 port 41336 [preauth]
Feb  4 09:38:19 sshd[75212]: Accepted password for vmadmin from 195.13.162.165 port 54564 ssh2
Feb  4 09:38:19 sshd[75212]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user vmadmin by (uid=0)
Feb  4 09:38:19 systemd-logind[1180]: New session 15026 of user vmadmin.
Feb  4 09:38:23 sshd[75293]: Invalid user vivek123 from 14.207.24.36 port 40822
Feb  4 09:38:23 sshd[75293]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb  4 09:38:23  sshd[75293]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=14.207.24.36
Feb  4 09:38:24 sshd[75293]: Failed password for invalid user vivek123 from 14.207.24.36 port 40822 ssh2
Feb  4 09:38:25 sshd[75293]: Received disconnect from 14.207.24.36 port 40822:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb  4 09:38:25  sshd[75293]: Disconnected from invalid user vivek123 14.207.24.36 port 40822 [preauth]
Feb  4 09:38:25 sshd[75301]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=111.204.157.197  user=root
Feb  4 09:38:25 sshd[75302]: Invalid user pen from 106.12.25.123 port 39328
Feb  4 09:38:25 sshd[75302]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb  4 09:38:25  sshd[75302]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=106.12.25.123
Feb  4 09:38:28  sshd[75301]: Failed password for root from 111.204.157.197 port 44082 ssh2
Feb  4 09:38:28  sshd[75302]: Failed password for invalid user pen from 106.12.25.123 port 39328 ssh2
Feb  4 09:38:28  sshd[75301]: Received disconnect from 111.204.157.197 port 44082:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb  4 09:38:28 sshd[75301]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 111.204.157.197 port 44082 [preauth]
Feb  4 09:38:28 sshd[75302]: Received disconnect from 106.12.25.123 port 39328:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb  4 09:38:28 sshd[75302]: Disconnected from invalid user pen 106.12.25.123 port 39328 [preauth] 
...
```

I m PHP programmer with with little knowledge about server logs, config and security. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** I found another interesting thing on `syslog`

```
Feb  6 06:59:31 systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Feb  6 06:59:42 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Feb  6 06:59:42 systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Feb  6 06:59:44 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Feb  6 06:59:44 kernel: [601324.484125] audit: type=1400 audit(1580965184.428:24): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=56672 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb  6 06:59:50 systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
```

At this case it looks like it is not Brute Force Attack rights?
If so what is happening here?

Comment: either that and successful, or something sent SIGTERM to mysqld, or something executed a command to stop mysqld.

Comment: @akuzminsky any solution that you could advice?

Comment: @Ingus After login to MySQL, what is result of SELECT @@max_connect_errors; ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad practice to have sshd and/or MySQL publicly accessible. Configure your firewall so that the services are accessible only from the sources that need to touch them. This will be a good starting point. Most probably your web application is running on the same host as the MySQL daemon and if this is the case there is no reason for it to be listening on any other IP except 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I got told that firewall will still allow to do it

Comment: I would say that running a server without any kind of firewall completely amazes me. Firewall is an integral part of application security. It is of course not going to solve all of your problems because it is not magic. But can severely limit the attack surface. You should apply a correctly configured for your application firewall ASAP.

Comment: Ok Thanks for info! I will look at firewall case ASAP. .. I added edit on question with `syslog` could you take a look at that?

Comment: It seems that you are using the desktop version of Ubuntu on your server. I really hope this is not a production server. What is stopping your MySQL database is the daily upgrade. There is an option to disable it by using `sudo systemctl stop apt-daily.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload` or marking the current version of MySQL on hold  by `sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>`

Comment: "It seems that you are using the desktop version of Ubuntu on your server. I really hope this is not a production server." Why so? Will test your suggestien about stopping that update!